# How can I programmatically generate a thumbnail of a PDF with iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, pdf, cocoa-touch

We're displaying PDF content using `UIWebViews` at the moment.  Ideally I would like to be able to display thumbnails in the `UITableView` without loading many different `UIWebViews` concurrently... they're slow enough loading one document - never mind 10+!

How do I go about doing this?

I've thought about screen capturing a document loaded using `UIDocumentInteractionController` or `UIWebView` but this means they'd all have to be thumbnailed before displaying the table.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Apple supply a whole bunch of methods down at the `CoreGraphics` level for drawing PDF content directly. As far as I'm aware, none of it is neatly packaged up at the `UIKit` level, so it may not be a good fit for your project at this point, especially if you're not as comfortable down at the C level. However, the relevant function is `CGContextDrawPDFPage;` per the normal `CoreGraphics` way of things there are other methods to create a PDF reference from a data source and then to get a page reference from a PDF. You'll then need to deal with scaling and translating to the view you want, and be warned that you'll need to perform a horizontal flip because PDFs (and OS X) use the lower left as the origin whereas iOS uses the top left. Example code, off the top of my head:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(thumbnailSize);
CGPDFDocumentRef pdfRef = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithProvider( (CGDataProviderRef)instanceOfNSDataWithPDFInside );
CGPDFPageRef pageRef = CGPDFDocumentGetPage(pdfRef, 1); // get the first page

CGContextRef contextRef = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

// ignore issues of transforming here; depends on exactly what you want and
// involves a whole bunch of normal CoreGraphics stuff that is nothing to do
// with PDFs
CGContextDrawPDFPage(contextRef, pageRef);

UIImage *imageToReturn = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

// clean up
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
CGPDFDocumentRelease(pdfRef);

return imageToReturn;
```

At a guess, you'll probably want to use `CGPDFPageGetBoxRect(pageRef, kCGPDFCropBox)` to get the page's crop box and then work out how to scale/move that to fit your image size.

Probably easier for your purposes is the `-renderInContext:` method on `CALayer` (see [QA 1703](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa2010/qa1703.html)) — the old means of getting a screenshot was `UIGetScreenImage`, but that was never really official API and was seemingly temporarily allowed only because of the accidental approval of RedLaser. With the code in the QA you can rig yourself up to get a UIImage from any other view without that view having to be on screen. Which possibly resolves some of your issue with screen capturing? Though it means you can support OS 4.x only.

In either case, PDFs just don't draw that quickly. You probably need to populate the table then draw the thumbnails on a background thread, pushing them upwards when available. You can't actually use UIKit objects safely on background threads but all the `CoreGraphics` stuff is safe.

Answer (score 13):

Here is sample code considering transformation. :)

```
NSURL* pdfFileUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:finalPath];
CGPDFDocumentRef pdf = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL((CFURLRef)pdfFileUrl);
CGPDFPageRef page;

CGRect aRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 70, 100); // thumbnail size
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(aRect.size);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
UIImage* thumbnailImage;


NSUInteger totalNum = CGPDFDocumentGetNumberOfPages(pdf);

for(int i = 0; i < totalNum; i++ ) {


    CGContextSaveGState(context);
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0.0, aRect.size.height);
    CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);

    CGContextSetGrayFillColor(context, 1.0, 1.0);
    CGContextFillRect(context, aRect);


    // Grab the first PDF page
    page = CGPDFDocumentGetPage(pdf, i + 1);
    CGAffineTransform pdfTransform = CGPDFPageGetDrawingTransform(page, kCGPDFMediaBox, aRect, 0, true);
    // And apply the transform.
    CGContextConcatCTM(context, pdfTransform);

    CGContextDrawPDFPage(context, page);

    // Create the new UIImage from the context
    thumbnailImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    //Use thumbnailImage (e.g. drawing, saving it to a file, etc)

    CGContextRestoreGState(context);

}


UIGraphicsEndImageContext();    
CGPDFDocumentRelease(pdf);
```

Comment: Hi alones, I'm using your code to get PDF thumbnails. It seems like CGContextConcatCTM(context, pdfTransform) line produces a memory bottleneck, I found out that if I leave this line out, then it's OK. But I can't leave it out because I need this for a proper thumbnail. Do you have an idea about how can we improve this? Thx btw...

Comment: this one works for me... the one above i dont know why but it generated a dummy or garbage thumbnail... thanks...

Comment: doc's say UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext() isn't thread safe

Comment: this one is working. The accepted answer is generating some blank image

Answer (score 2):

Here is a swift 3 method for generating a UIImage thumbnail for a pdf page

```
static func getThumbnailForPDF(_ urlString:String, pageNumber:Int) -> UIImage? {
    let bundle = Bundle.main
    let path = bundle.path(forResource: urlString, ofType: "pdf")
    let pdfURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: path!)

    let pdf = CGPDFDocument(pdfURL as CFURL )!
    let page = pdf.page(at: pageNumber)!
    let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100.0, height: 70.0) //Image size here

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size)
    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!

    context.saveGState()
    context.translateBy(x: 0, y: rect.height)
    context.scaleBy(x: 1.0, y: -1.0)
    context.setFillColor(gray: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)
    context.fill(rect)


    let pdfTransform = page.getDrawingTransform(CGPDFBox.mediaBox, rect: rect, rotate: 0, preserveAspectRatio: true)
    context.concatenate(pdfTransform)
    context.drawPDFPage(page)

    let thumbImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    context.restoreGState()

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return thumbImage
}
```

Comment: Hey Emil, you're about 7 years late to the party — but thanks none the less for keeping this question alive for anyone facing the same issue ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If you use PDFKit, there is a method for `PDFPage` called `thumbnail`. It is available in iOS11 and above and does the job in just a few lines of code. Here is a simple method for generating a thumbnail of a given page in a `PDFDocument`.

```swift
func makeThumbnail(pdfDocument: PDFDocument?, page: Int) -> UIImage? {
        return pdfDocument?.page(at: page)?.thumbnail(of: CGSize(width: 40, height: 40), for: .artBox)
    }
```

Unfortunately it misses official documentation (see, https://developer.apple.com/documentation/pdfkit/pdfpage/2869834-thumbnail). However, there are some comments accessible in the code for `PDFPage`.

Comment: Appreciate the response. Unfortunately this method is incredibly slow if generating multiple thumbnails.

Comment: This worked for me