# how to generate ppt, doc thumbnail in iOS

Tags: ios, uiwebview, thumbnails, powerpoint, doc

As the title says,

I'm essentially looking for a way to generate a thumbnail from a .DOC, .DOCX, or .PPT file in iOS in background.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is not exactly the type of file you want, but is a starting point:

[How can I programatically generate a thumbnail of a PDF with the iPhone SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4107850/how-can-i-programatically-generate-a-thumbnail-of-a-pdf-with-the-iphone-sdk)

http://davidbits.blogspot.com.es/2012/10/ios-getting-thumbnail-of-pdf-document.html

Comment: it's completely different.. I know i have to load the ppt in a webview and then make a screenshoot of it, but i don't know how to do it in a synchronous way in a background thread..

Comment: Ive been looking for a way to do this for a long time and I seriously don't think there's a way to do it asynchronously which is pretty absurd.

Answer (score -1):

For opening anything (PDF, Pages, Word, Numbers, Excel, Images etc) that the Mail.app or Safari can open, you usually use the UIWebView.

```
UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0F, 0.0F, 320.0F,    480.0F)];
NSURL *pdfURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.something.com/myFile.pdf"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:pdfURL];
[webView loadRequest:request];
[self.view addSubview:webView];
```