# Creating Thumbnail Image From PPT

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, powerpoint

I need to show list of posts in a `UITableview` where user posts images, videos, documents texts etc.

For the post PPT (powerpoint presentation) which will be uploaded over the server, I need to create a thumbnail image for the PPT file and need to upload over the server along with PPT file.

What is the best way to generate a thumbnail or preview image of a PPT file which can be represented in `UIImageView` ?

Comment: see this link.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4107850/how-can-i-programatically-generate-a-thumbnail-of-a-pdf-with-the-iphone-sdk

Comment: I guess it is for PDF file, not for PPT. @NiravKotecha

Comment: not tested but found this link in github. might be help you.. https://github.com/adamwulf/PowerPointToUIImage

Comment: You can load ppt file in webview and from loaded webview you can take screen shot or get image from it's context.

Comment: @AnandSuthar for loading PPT in a `UIWebView`, user needs to wait until whole PPT gets loaded into it and on the completion of it, it will start conversation to thumbnail. This is approach is useful but at the same time it is time consuming.

Comment: @Bhargav Soni, No If ppt is in your local bundle or downloaded then it will not take much time to load. You can make your webview hidden and render your ppt without showing it to user. It will take maximum 1 sec. to load ppt in webview.